# Binding a templated standard library function

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you do this? The alternative requires wrapping `std::generate` in a lambda or `std::function` and that's undesirable.

```
int main()
{
    using array_int = std::array<int, 10>;
    std::vector<array_int> vec(10);
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        std::bind(std::generate, std::placeholders::_1, []() { return 0; }));

    return 0;
}
```

As noted the problem is `std::generate` takes an iterator pair. Let's pretend they're boost ranges instead:

```
boost::for_each(vec,
    boost::bind(boost::generate, _1, []() { return 0; }));
```

Comment: You are using a lambda anyway, so why is one more undesirable? I gave up wresting with this bind syntax long ago. Just use lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're really going to pass something more useful to `generate`, because those arrays will already be filled with zeros, because `vector` value-initializes them.

Your bind expression will not pass the right number of arguments to `generate`, so specifying which specialization of `generate` you want is not the only problem. In order to state the specialization you need to know the type of the generator you want to pass, which is a lambda, so you need to hoist that out:

```
auto gen = [] { return 0; };
```

Then you need to say which `generate` you want:

```
std::generate<array_int::iterator, decltype(gen)>
```

Then you need to pass the right arguments to it:

```
std::bind(std::generate<array_int::iterator, decltype(gen)>,
          std::bind(&array_int::begin, std::placeholders::_1),
          std::bind(&array_int::end, std::placeholders::_1),
          gen));
```

This still won't work, because `array_int::begin` and `array_int::end` are overloaded, so you need to cast them to `array_int::iterator (array_int::*)()` to get the non-const versions.

```
auto gen = [] { return 0; };
using memfunc = array_int::iterator (array_int::*)();;
std::bind(std::generate<array_int::iterator, decltype(gen)>,
          std::bind((memfunc)&array_int::begin, std::placeholders::_1),
          std::bind((memfunc)&array_int::end, std::placeholders::_1),
          gen));
```

You can make that a little bit simpler with `generate_n` since you know the size, and maybe using `data()` instead of `begin()`, although you still need to cast it:

```
auto gen = [] { return 0; };
using memfunc = int* (array_int::*)();;
std::bind(std::generate_n<int*, int, decltype(gen)>,
          std::bind((memfunc)&array_int::data, std::placeholders::_1),
          10,
          gen));
```

Or you could just use a lambda:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](array_int& a) {
  std::generate(a.begin(), a.end(), []{ return 0; });
});
```

If you want to call `boost::generate` instead it's a bit easier as you don't need a nested bind expression, but you still need the type of the generator:

```
auto gen = [] { return 0; };
std::bind(boost::generate<array_int, decltype(gen)>,
          std::placeholders::_1
          gen);
```

Or with a lambda:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](array_int& a) {
  boost::generate(a, []{ return 0; });
});
```

Comment: Let's pretend that they're boost ranges instead. Then only one argument is required.

Comment: OK, that's as easy as telling the compiler which `generate` speciliazation you want: `boost::generate<array_int, decltype(gen)>`